# Leaves on my Dracaena reflexa have died because of cold and I trimmed them

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, leaves, pruning, dracaena

I am currently located in Srinagar (India) the winter has been a tad too harsh this year with night temperatures plummeting to -7 degrees C all the leaves on my Dracaena reflexa gehich I had forgotten outside) have dried up because of cold so I trimmed the crowns and let the stems stand bare. I’ve brought it indoors though but I’m not sure about it’s survival.. any idea folks

Comment: That's about all you can do. Keep feeding/watering/fertilizing it and hope for the best and keep it indoors.